# String Formatting Error in Python Challenge Even Though It's Correct in IDE

Tags: python, string, syntax, formatting

I was solving some Python challenges on Edabit and I encountered this question. I believe that my code is ok and also tested in PyCharm, which gave me the expected result.

Why string formatting gives me the Syntax Error on Edabit challenges even though it is correct?[image]

Comment: Check the python version they are using. f strings are only available from 3.6+ onwards.

Comment: Yup, looks like Edabit uses old Python version. Try using `str.format()` instead of f-string (Just in that case, generally I think f-strings are a better option)

Answer (score 0):

For Python versions before 3.6 you won't have available the currently preferred [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals). Up to Python 3.6 you could use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Example for this:

```
def example_dothat(lst):
    RTotal = round(sum(lst), 1)
    print("{} ohms".format(RTotal)
```